# JQuery selector: (class1 OR class2) AND (class3 OR class4) - how do I write this selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a webpage in which elements are displayed and there is a filtering option on the side.  Users can filter in multiple categories.

This is sort of like Amazon.com, where you can filter the results of your search by price or brand, etc.

So if my user checks both $10-$25 and $25-$50, but not $50-$100, or any other price range, then the selector should return items that match either $10-$25 OR $25-$50, but should not return items that fall in any other price range.  If in addition the user checks "blue" and "red" but does not check any other color, then the selector should return items that are either blue OR red, but it should maintain the original selections on the price range.

All these options are given as classes, so I want a selector that looks something like:

`(.tenToTwentyfive OR .twentyfiveFift) AND (.Blue OR .Red)`.

Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure with the way you worded your question, however something like this should work: `$(".tenToTwentyfive,.twentyfiveFift,.Blue,.Red")`

Comment: There's always context as well, `$('.blue, .red', '.tenToTwentyfive, .twentyfiveFift')`

Comment: @KevinB: Wouldn't that select a blue/red item regardless of its price, thus not satisfying the filter?

Comment: @PaoloBergantino Yes it would. It isn't clear in his question whether that's his intention or not. (at least it wasn't to me, which is why i made a comment and not an answer.)

Comment: @KevinB: Pretty sure the intent is that if a user has selections in multiple groups of criteria an item needs to match at least 1 criteria in each group. That's the way his logic statement reads and the way I would expect a site to work in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) :

```
$('.tenToTwentyfive, .twentyfiveFift').filter('.Blue, .Red');
```

If you really need to have everything in one selector (which means in my opinion you're using a badly designed plugin), you could use

```
'.tenToTwentyfive.Blue, .tenToTwentyfive.Red, .twentyfiveFift.Blue, .twentyfiveFift.Red'
```

Comment: This is great.  However, the way I'm writing my code, I'd like to be able to build the selector string all at once.  I'm working with Isotope, and it expects to be given a fully-formed JQuery Selector as an argument.  You can see what I mean at this link: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html (about 2 paras down, under the section "jQuery Script").  I need to call a method as follows: `$container.isotope({  filter: filter_string });`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful update re: everything in one selector.  I'm not sure the plugin is badly designed or my understanding of how it all works is not deep enough.  For now, this is my understanding of how to get it to do what I want.  Again, thanks much.

Comment: okay, now suppose I have six categories and each category contains six items and the user selects the first five items in each category... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353118/javascript-isotope-how-can-i-intelligently-create-multiple-groups-of-filters-t

Answer (score 2):

Use `.filter()`

```
$('.tenToTwentyfive , .twentyfiveFift').filter('.Blue , .Red')
```

This will select all the elements with `.tenToTwentyfive OR  .twentyfiveFift`

The `.filter()` will only select the elements that have `.Blue OR .Red` among the previously selected elements.

Comment: Wondering ? what might be the reason for the super fast Downvotes ;)